# Check if an ionic page is loaded from app.component.ts

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I know how to check if a page is loaded from the page itself using one of the lifecycle hooks.

What I want is to find out if a page was loaded once I set the `rootPage` in `app.component.ts`. Currently, I'm publishing an event from `ionViewDidLoad` of the page back to `app.component.ts`, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

Comment: Why not to have a service with observable for communication?

Answer (score 0):

> Currently, I'm publishing an event from `ionViewDidLoad` of the page
>   back to `app.component.ts`, but I was wondering if there was a better
>   way to do this.

That's the best way to do it. Otherwise you'd need to create a shared service with an observable just for that, and the result would be exactly the same. So **yes, using [Ionic Events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) is the best way to do that**.